# Laravel populate dropdown options

Tags: php, laravel

I have options for my products and I want show them as dropdown to let users choose from them, here is screenshot of my last result

[image: screenshot]

As you can see I have 2 color row and 3 size row in my table which I want to be 1 color row and 1 size row then in dropdown be total options of color and sizes.

Here is my blade code:

```
<div class="options">
  <h3>options:</h3>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
      @foreach($product->suboptions as $option)
      <tr>
       <td style="width: 150px;">{{ $option->option->title }}</td> //this shows Color,Sizes, etc.
       <td class="text-left">
        <select name="" id="">
         <option value="{{$option->id}}">{{$option->title}} - {{ number_format($option->price, 0) }}</option> //This shows options like Gray,Red, XL, etc.
        </select>
       </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any idea?

## Update

here is my controller code:

```
public function showproduct($slug) {
    $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    $images = DB::table('images')->where('imageable_id', '=', $product->id)->get();
    $product->addVisit();
    $arrivaltime = Carbon::now()->addWeekdays($product->arrivialin);
    $mytime = Carbon::now();
    $rates = $product->ratings()->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
    $random = Product::inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
    $discounts = Discount::where('product_id', '=', $product->id)->get();
    return view('front.single', compact('product', 'images', 'arrivaltime', 'mytime', 'rates', 'random', 'discounts'));
  }
```

Comment: If you want a clean view, fix the structure or rebuild the array. Or have a *tracking* var which determines where to put the *$option* in a new row or in the select which will make your view ugly as your need to do buffering.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone obviously I want clean view and that's why i asked this question, would you mind to help me fix it please?

Comment: Loop over the `$product->suboptions` in the controller and build a new array/object. Define the key as the type [size|color] and place each option as a child. then you can just loop over it with 2 foreaches

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I updated my question with my controller code would you mind help me with that loop you've mentioned? PS: sorry not good at looping in controller!